# Principal $n$th Root

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a simple question, but I am having a glitch somewhere:

What is the principal $n$th root of $(-9)^{1/2}$?

I keep getting $3$ and the book has $3i$.  I know it has to do with the $-9$, but I am failing to see it.

Comment: Does $-9=9\,i^2$ help ?

Comment: $3$ is not even a root, the other (non-principal) root is $-3i$

Comment: I am instructed to use the long W sub K formula.

Comment: Insteat of "principal $n$th root of $(-9)^{1/2}$, might you have meant "principal square root of $-9$"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @DavidHouse : What is the "long W sub K" formula? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Especially you should realize that the book has given a correct root by observing that $(3i)^2 = -9$, and you given an incorrect root by observing that $3^2 = 9 \ne -9$

Comment: I don't have a good way of typing it in, but I think my problem way Arg(z).

Comment: Is Arg(z) 0 or pi?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in polar form $-9 = 9e^{i\pi+2ni\pi}$ and from that you can calculate powers: $\sqrt{-9} = \sqrt{9}\sqrt{e^{i\pi + 2ni\pi}} = 3e^{i\pi/2+ni\pi}$ then it's only a matter of selecting which branch you want, the principal means $n=0$ so its $3e^{i\pi/2} = 3i$

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a root from a negative number unless you work with complex-numbers.

$i^2 = -1$ so $-9 = 9i^2$

sqaure root of $9i^2 = 3i$

Comment: definitely helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The principal $n$th root of a complex number $z = |z| e^{i \arg z} = r e^{i\varphi}$ is 
$$z^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{r}e^{i \varphi /n}$$
For $z=-9$ you have $r=9,\,\sqrt[2]{9}=3$ and $\varphi = \pi,\, e^{i \pi/2}=i$ and therefore $(-9)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 3i$.